# How do I get routeparams in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routeparams

I am new to angularjs and below part is always quite confusing to me

```
angular.module('bookYourSeatApp', [])
    .factory('seats', SeatsFactory)
    .controller('mainCtrl', MainCtrl);
```

I want to get routeparams and I tried

```
function SeatsFactory($rootScope, $timeout, $routeParams) {
```

and

```
function MainCtrl(seats, $routeParams) {
```

and inserting $routeparams at few other places and I get error everywhere. Code is in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandskies/nyzxf2oj/10/). How do I inject $routeparams in the below code?

```
angular.module('bookYourSeatApp', [])
    .factory('seats', SeatsFactory)
    .controller('mainCtrl', MainCtrl);

function SeatsFactory($rootScope, $timeout) {


    //more code
    var factory = {
        map: seats,
        setSeats: setSeats,
        select: selectSeats,
        checkedSeats: checkedSeats,
        availCount: {},
        setAvailCount: function(count) {
            console.log('avail', count);
            checkSelected(count);
        }
    };

    return factory
}

function MainCtrl(seats) {
    // console.log($routeParams);
    var vm = this;
    angular.extend(vm, {
        seats: seats,
        selectionCount: [//[0,1,2,3,4],[
        {id: 0, val: 0}, // object for two-way binding
        ],
        selectedCount: 0
    });

    vm.selectedCount = vm.selectionCount[0];
    seats.setAvailCount(vm.selectedCount);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('bookYourSeatApp', [])
    .factory('seats', SeatsFactory)
    .controller('mainCtrl', MainCtrl);

   MainCtrl.$inject = ['$routeParams'];

function SeatsFactory($rootScope, $timeout) {


    //more code
    var factory = {
        map: seats,
        setSeats: setSeats,
        select: selectSeats,
        checkedSeats: checkedSeats,
        availCount: {},
        setAvailCount: function(count) {
            console.log('avail', count);
            checkSelected(count);
        }
    };

    return factory
}

function MainCtrl(seats, $routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);
    var vm = this;
    angular.extend(vm, {
        seats: seats,
        selectionCount: [//[0,1,2,3,4],[
        {id: 0, val: 0}, // object for two-way binding
        ],
        selectedCount: 0
    });

    vm.selectedCount = vm.selectionCount[0];
    seats.setAvailCount(vm.selectedCount);
}
```

I recommend that do not inject $routeParams as the init params of a service. Instead, inject it in controllers.factory is singleton

Comment: @raju, pass the `$routeParams` value to factory function as `seats.setAvailCount(vm.selectedCount, $routeParams.param);`

Comment: when I $routeParams in the function MainCtrl line it doesnt work properly - look at https://jsfiddle.net/sandskies/nyzxf2oj/10/

Comment: `MainCtrl.$inject = ['$routeParams'];' inject $routeParams.please see edited answer

Comment: @raju, you need to inject '$routeParams' to your controller before using it.

Comment: I tried this in fiddle also and its not working. can you edit to create working fiddle?

Comment: @raju, we can not implement this with a fiddle,

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed these injection before your create the factory and controller

```
SeatsFactory.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$timeout'] //make sure if you need 2 params in your SeatsFactory function, inject 2 params as well here
MainCtrl.$inject = ['seats', '$routeParams'] //as well the controller
```

Remember: Service/Factory is a shared resources which is singleton, you might not want this singleton received some dependent params, just pass data that the service/factory need to proceed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this in fiddle also and its not working. can you edit to create working fiddle?

Comment: Have you configured the `$routeProvider` in your config?